# Google Translate API python not working each time, sometimes I get the output sometimes I don't?

Tags: python, analytics, google-translation-api

```
import google_trans_new
from google_trans_new 
import google_translator

translator = google_translator()  

langd = []                                                    
for i in range(10):                                         
  try:          
    t= translator.detect(df['Title'][i])
  except:                                                       
    t='no'    
  langd.append(t)


df["Language"] = langd
df.head(10)
```

Here is the code which I am using, and I get the output sometimes and sometimes I don't.

Output:

Title|  Description  |                              Language

0    |   तूर विकणे आहे  20किटल      |                      no

1    | Foolkobi Holsel ret madhe milel  |              no

2   | power tiller खरेदी करायचा आहे VST Shakti |          no

3   | जीरा बेचना है                                |       no

Getting my output "no" most times, dont know why!

Comment: Start by finding out what exception is raised instead of just ignoring it. Also consider to replace the image link with the text of what you want to show. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @HernánAlarcón Thanks for the tip, but I am not getting any exceptions

Comment: I believe you are, because the Language column is full of `no`.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón The code is directly going into except block if I wait for sometime, it goes through and I get the expected output